# Get the size of the directory having unicode filenames in c++

Tags: c++11, unicode, filesystems, boost-filesystem

I want to calculate the size(in bytes) of a directory, here is my algorithm using boost::filesystem

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

// this will go through the directories and sub directories and when any
// file is detected it call the 'handler' function with the file path
void iterate_files_in_directory(const path& directory,
                                     function<void(const path&)> handler)
{
    if(exists(directory))
        if(is_directory(directory)){
            directory_iterator itr(directory);
            for(directory_entry& e: itr){
                if (is_regular_file(e.path())){
                    handler(e.path().string());
                }else if (is_directory(e.path())){
                    iterate_files_in_directory(e.path(),handler);
                }
            }
        }
}

uint64_t get_directory_size(const path& directory){
    uint64_t size = 0;
    iterate_files_in_directory(directory,[&size](const path& file){
        size += file_size(file);
    });
    return size;
}
```

It works fine when directory contains file with simple file names (i.e, without any Unicode character), but when any file with a Unicode character found it throws an exception:

what():

```
boost::filesystem::file_size: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't know if you have seen [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Class-path-Constructors), but I think you need to somehow explicitly be using `std::wstring` for it to work?  I have not tried, and that could be totally wrong...

Comment: Try removing `.string()` here. `handler(e.path().string());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I have removed `.string()` in `handler(e.path().string())` and that's all here is my new code

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

// this will go through the directories and sub directories and when any
// file is detected it call the 'handler' function with the file path
void iterate_files_in_directory(const path& directory,
                                     function<void(const path&)> handler)
{
    if(exists(directory))
        if(is_directory(directory)){
            directory_iterator itr(directory);
            for(directory_entry& e: itr){
                if (is_regular_file(e.path())){
                    handler(e.path()); // here was the bug in the previous code
                }else if (is_directory(e.path())){
                    iterate_files_in_directory(e.path(),handler);
                }
            }
        }
}

uint64_t get_directory_size(const path& directory){
    uint64_t size = 0;
    iterate_files_in_directory(directory,[&size](const path& file){
        size += file_size(file);
    });
    return size;
}
```